# How does this expression reduce to the erfc?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, integration, error-function

I'm working on characteristic functions, and in this process I have came across the following step in a proof

$$
\frac{i}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\tau_k\mu^2/\sigma^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2v^2\tau_k}\frac{\text{d} v}{v - i\mu / \sigma^2} + 1 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\Bigg[{\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\tau_k}}\Bigg]
$$

I received the proof from which this step is taken from an 'integrals guru' my professor contacted. So I guess it is correct, but I do not see what substitution would be used to go from left to right in one step. For reference, the complementary error function $\operatorname{erfc}[.]$ is defined as:

$$
\operatorname{erfc}[x] = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm  dt \\
$$

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hint.  First do this simpler integral for $a>0$ ... $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac {1}{{u}^{2}+a}{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {{u}^{2}}{2}}}}}\,{\rm d}u=\frac{\pi{{\rm e}^{a/2}}}{\sqrt{a}}{\rm erfc} \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}\sqrt {a}} \right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to look up some special functions, in particular the integral representation of the Fadeeva function.

The Fadeeva function is defined (for complex arguments) as $w(z)=e^{-z^2} \operatorname{erfc}(-i z)$.

The integral representation of the Faddeva function is

$w(z)=\frac{i}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{z-t}dt$

which can be transformed to your problem with some simple substitutions.